# Is it possible to save an image using Parse rest API to the _User class?

Tags: javascript, ajax, parse-platform

Parse.com, Rest API and JavaScript SDK.

The below code takes a image uploaded by the user and uploads it into the Parse cloud. The section section also lets you add it to a parse class.

It works correctly when I use a class I've created, but I want the image added to the _User class.

Is this not possible?

I've tried
 var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User';

and
 var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User';

```
$('#imageFile').bind("change", function(e) {

var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
file = files[0];
uploadFile(file);
});


function uploadFile(file) {

var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + file.name;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'x');
request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'x');
   request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", file.type);
 },

   url: serverUrl,
  data: file,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
 success: function(data) {
alert("File available at: " + data.url);
   saveUserPhotoToDatabase(data.url);
  },
   error: function(data) {
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     alert(obj.error);
   }
});
}

                        function saveUserPhotoToDatabase(image_url) {

var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User';

// save the user=some_user_name GET parameter with the url to the image
var queryDict = {};
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]});

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
beforeSend: function(request) {
  request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'x');
  request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", 'x');
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
},
url: serverUrl,
data: JSON.stringify({
    user:queryDict.user,
    imageUrl:image_url
}),
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function(data) {
    alert("Upload OK!");
},
error: function(data) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  alert(obj.error);
}
});


                }
```